# Best way to design one property across multiple types (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net

I have requirement leading me down this path...

```
public interface IThing
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
public class ThingA : IThing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class ThingB : IThing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public long Value { get; set; }
}
public class ThingC : IThing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

The challenge is modeling something with a Value that can be string/long/bool. I'm finding this to be difficult to work with due to constant casting checks, and the interface itself is not useful. Is there a conventional approach to tackling this problem I'm not aware of? Or a pattern someone has found to work well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean the type of the property would be different or both name and property would be different? It sounds like a generic interface would do it.

Comment: Just the type is different - the property name must be the same in all cases.

Comment: There is no way to provide useful answer without information on how exactly you are using these types so it causes you problems. Since there is nothing common between the types you are interested in (string/long/bool) it is very hard to suggest something that universally will simplify code. Generics (as suggested) is unlikely going to help as there no commonality between these types that can be used by generics methods...

Comment: Agree with @AlexeiLevenkov.  Was your hope to be able to put the `Value` property into the interface `IThing`, and access it from the interface? More information about the "requirement leading me down this path" will help shape the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this design... I needed to have some kind of base I could instantiate before knowing what the value type was going to be. I was not able to avoid the hassles of this approach (a lot of casting) by using generics, and also prevented me from having an agnostic base. Would love to see how to get more usability out of an interface (if possible) for this scenario.

```
public class BaseThing
{
    public string Id { get; set; }        
    public IValueConfig Configuration { get; set; }
    public string CommonProp { get; set; }...
}

public interface IValueConfig
{
    ValueType Type { get; }
}

public class RangeVal : IValueConfig
{
    public ValueType Type => ValueType.Range;
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string UniqueProp { get; set; }...
}

public class StateVal : IValueConfig
{
    public ValueType Type => ValueType.State;
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string UniqueProp { get; set; }...
}

public class BooleanVal : IValueConfig
{
    public ValueType Type => ValueType.Boolean;
    public bool Value { get; set; }
    public string UniqueProp { get; set; }...
}

public enum ValueType
{
    Range,
    State,
    Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want generics:

```
public interface IThing
{
   string Id { get; set; }
}
public class Thing<T> : IThing
{
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
      var thingA = new Thing<int>();
      var thingB = new Thing<string>();
    
      thingA.Id = "A";
      thingA.Value = 42;
    
      thingB.Id = "B";
      thingB.Value = "Is a B";
    
      Console.WriteLine(thingA.Value);
      Console.WriteLine(thingB.Value);
   }
}
```

Where you would have a base class, which inherits from your interface, with the type of the value you want.

Comment: I suspect it totally useless for OP as they seem to need to know what type of the value is stored... which generics by themselves don't eliminate at all... Indeed you can check/cast to slightly fancier looking type (`Thing<string>` vs. `ThingA` ), but whether it is enough of improvement ...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov yes, without further clarification it's hard to guess where any pattern he is using falls apart. Assuming his question was what he at least sort of meant though, I suspect this would work. Of course, assuming is exactly where these questions and answers sometimes get really weird...

Comment: I think the idea was to use the interface to handle the Value property, but @AlexeiLevenkov makes a good point about the actual usability of such interface.